# g++ error expected a type, got ‘classname’

Tags: compiler-errors, g++

Using the following code with g++:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<int> array;
typedef std::vector<array *> list;


struct time{
    int beg;
    int end;
    time(){
    beg=0;
    end=0;
    }
};

void explore(int v, std::vector<bool> & visited, list & l, std::vector<time> & times);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I got errors:

expected a type, got ‘time’

template argument 2 is invalid

With MSVC++ 2013 all ok. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I found answer: I have to add `typedef struct time "mytipe"` and all works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `<iostream>` provided with g++ is recursively including the [C `<time.h>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono), which declares the function [`time_t time(time_t*)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time).  In parsing template instantiation arguments, function identifiers are preferred to names of types, even where the corresponding template parameter is a type.

A workaround would be to write `std::vector<struct time>`, but it would probably be better to use a namespace or use a name that is not used by the C standard.